# Nested smart components in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I tried to make a reusable component in redux.
The idea behind this is that I am creating a smart combobox and place it several times inside an other component or smart component.

Lets assume the only job from this combobox is to display countries, allow to add new countries and tell the parent what country is selected.

The parent dont have to pass the available countries down to the combobox only the onValueChanged event so the parent knows what country is selected.

This results in the following structure (The items are not really countries to keep it simple but you should get the idea behind it):

```
//Constants (appConstants.ts)
export const SmartCombobox = {
    ADD_ITEM: 'SMART_COMBOBOX/ADD_ITEM'
}

//Action creator (smartComboboxAction.ts)
import { SmartCombobox } from '../constants/appConstants';

export function AddItem() {
    return {
        type: SmartCombobox.ADD_ITEM
    };
}

//Reducer (smartCombobox.ts)
import { SmartCombobox } from '../constants/appConstants';

const initialState = ['Item 1']

export default function items(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SmartCombobox.ADD_ITEM:
            let items = ['Item' + Math.random().toString()]
            return state.concat(items);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

//Container (smartCombobox.ts)
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { default as SmartCombobox } from '../components/combobox';
import * as ComboboxActions from '../actions/smartComboboxAction';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        items: state.items        
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        comboboxActions: bindActionCreators(<any>ComboboxActions, dispatch)
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SmartCombobox);
```

Then I am able to use it like this inside my component or smart component.
When I add a new item, every component that includes my smartCombobox would be synced and has the exact amout of items.

```
//Component (combobox.tsx)
import * as React from 'react';

interface SmartComboboxProps {
    items?: Array<any>,
    comboboxActions?: any,
    onValueChanged: Function
}

export default class SmartCombobox extends React.Component<SmartComboboxProps, any> {
    onValueChanged(event:any) {
        let selectedValue = event.target.value;
        const { onValueChanged } = this.props;

        onValueChanged(selectedValue);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // Call value changed for first selected item        
        this.props.onValueChanged(this.props.items[0]);
    }

    render() {
        const { comboboxActions } = this.props;

        let options = this.props.items.map(function (o) {
            return <option key={o} value={o}>{o}</option>
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <select style={{ width: "200px" }} name="SmartCombobox" onChange={ this.onValueChanged.bind(this) } >
                    { options }
                </select>
                <button onClick={ comboboxActions.AddItem }>Add item</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

[Final result (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSKoH.jpg)

Is this the correct approach for reusable components?
Or are there maybe any pitfalls I might forgot?

**There was also the idea that the combobox should be connected directly to an api because the app shouldn't know whats happening in here.

But this would break the idea of flux because I would need a state inside this component etc.

I was against that idea...**

Comment: I don't think this approach is wrong if it works. I don't think that connecting the component to an API is better than keeping it flux just because you might want to know somewhere else int he application when its loading that data (for example, if you had a global loading gif). On the other hand, you can use web components in react, and that pattern is not anti-pattern. You could use a polymer component that hooked into an API for this, and it wouldn't be the worst thing in the world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this the correct approach for reusable components?
>   Or are there maybe any pitfalls I might forgot

This approach is good.

> There was also the idea that the combobox should be connected directly to an api because the app shouldn't know whats happening in here.

You are right here. The source of truth (or rather truth setter) only needs to be one and therefore cannot be the component.

Comment: Thank you. Thought so :). One thing I have to think about now is if I should trigger the action for populating the combobox in the parent component or inside the smart combobox. The benefit would be, that the action would only be sent once when I call it in the parent after componentDidMount.

Comment: `One thing I have to think about now is if I should trigger the action for populating the combobox in the parent component or inside the smart combobox` The smart combo box should be populating from the redux store. Not *inside* just `redux-react` `@connect`

Comment: Sorry, I meant where I should call the action for populating. My smart combobox is already connected to the store. But when I call this action inside the combobox after componentDidMount it would get called 3 times for instance. But when I call the action outside the parent in the componentDidMount method, it only would get called once. But there is maybe a chance to forget it after I nest it inside the parent. Personaly I would prefer the call it once way.